# populate array of ids from same same collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of products where I've kept variants as an array of ids, but this array of ids are the `_ids` from the same collection. Now if I want to populate the ids how can I do that.

The collection looks like this.

So I tried to populate this as below but it does not work.

```
db.products.aggregate([
     ..........,
     {"$unwind": "$variantIdsArr" },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "$products",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "variantIdsArr",
        "as": "variantIdsArr"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$variantIdsArr" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "variantIdsArr": { "$push": "$variantIdsArr" }
      }},
     .........,
])
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/populate.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$lookup` has a typo:

```
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "$products", // This should be `products` instead of `$products`
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "localField": "variantIdsArr",
      "as": "variantIdsArr"
  }
}
```